# Access spring component from servlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, autowired

I have a controller (for example. MyManager) where I invoke method (for example myMethod() ) of component class (bean), for example MyComponent. I have I servlet where I want to invoke myMethod() . In servlet I have annotated MyManager by `@Autowired` annotation , despite this I got NullPointerException. I saw this kind of topic but it is not useful for me. For imagination I write little code :

```
public class myClass extends HttpServlet {

@Autowired
private MyComponent component;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
super.init(config);
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ... {

List<MyObject> objects =component.myMethod();  // Here is the problem, component is null

}

}

}
```

I make Spring configuration file "context.xml" and I got bean (component) object, but now I have problem with injected EntityManager in bean object. Now it is null , can anyone help me to solve this problem ?  Also update init() method.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
ApplicationContext con = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
component = (MyComponent) con.getBean("myBean");
}
```

Comment: Please post context.xml

Comment: Thanks I solved problem in another way, without servlet. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot autowire dependencies like that because Servlets are not Spring Beans. You need to do something like the following:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    component= applicationContext.getBean(MyComponent.class);
}
```

Also drop the `@Autowired` annotation from `component`

Comment: For this do I need application-context.xml file ?

Comment: You would need to have a Spring context defined in some way, most likely with application-context.xml

Comment: Is it okay if I create application-context.xml file in my project ? or can you point me the source where can I see how to define Spring Context ?

Comment: If is a perfectly good way to define a Spring Context. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/

Comment: It is probably better that you don't use Servlets unless you really need them, and instead use Spring MVC Controllers

Comment: I got bean object but I have another problem with injected EntityManager in bean. not it is null how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Please update your post so everyone can see what configuration you have for Spring